# Does it make sense to use ProfilePasswordPolicy metadata in an sfdx project?

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, metadata

When I interactively modify the "Password Policies":

[image: password policies]

in a couple of profiles in my scratch org and then run:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ProfilePasswordPolicy
```

zero `.profilePasswordPolicy` files are returned. And [these search results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=ProfilePasswordPolicy) point out that the naming of the files is not what you might expect.

When I manually created a `.profilePasswordPolicy` file and used on it:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy
```

I got his error message:

> No source-backed components present in the package.

Does it make sense (and is it possible) to include the [ProfilePasswordPolicy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm) metadata side by side with profiles in a project? Or is it more rational to manually modify the settings after the profile has been deployed or installed?

Comment: Does the outcome of having a password policy apply to a profile change based on one of your proposed options?

Comment: Hi @identigral, The `<ProfilePasswordPolicy>` includes a profile reference `<profile>Admin</profile>` that appears to link it to a single profile. Don;t know if that answers your question?

Comment: Yeah, sort of.  Sounds like applying the policy via sfdx works when profile already exists in the org work but does not work when both profile and policy are in the project def

Comment: In my case Admin is already there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. The answer is "yes it does". SFDX works as expected.

The new SFDX command structure includes his informative "preview" option that explains the root of my problem:

```
sf project deploy preview -d no-ns/main/default/profilePasswordPolicies  
...
Ignored [2] files. These files won't deploy because they're ignored by your .forceignore file.
 Type                  Fullname                                          Path                                                                                   
 ───────────────────── ───────────────────────────────────────────────── ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 ProfilePasswordPolicy Admin_profilePasswordPolicy1699382618             no-ns/main/default/profilePasswordPolicies/Admin_profilePasswordPolicy1699382618.prof… 
 ProfilePasswordPolicy CustomerCommunity_profilePasswordPolicy1699382618 no-ns/main/default/profilePasswordPolicies/CustomerCommunity_profilePasswordPolicy169…
```

i.e. the `.forceignore` file (created a long time ago) was doing its job correctly by ignoring this metadata type. Pity that the older commands just returned the way less helpful:

```
No source-backed components present in the package
```